# Ways to improve my program that dumps data into excel?

Tags: python, sql, microsoft-excel, vba, performance

So for work I have a project where I collect data from multiple databases and then dump it into excel. In my undergrad studying computer engineering I rarely did any excel automation nor do I know much about displaying data from databases since I came from more of a embedded systems background. I have been working recently to make a ton of improvements to this 'database viewer' that they use in excel and I want to make it even better. Generally, what are some ways I can improve the following?:

Before I did anything...:

- This program performs 16 queries (9 to SQL Server DBs and 7 to HANA DBs). Initially the entire thing was made around 2007 and written completely in VBA. As the company grew exponentially the VBA eventually got so slow that a full update of this 'database viewer' took more than 30 minutes to complete.
- A full update pulls all the information and then uses filters to sift through the most current data and then display it in excel. This program works with almost 20 different sheets in excel printing almost all of the data it pulls to the spreadsheet.
- The spreadsheet has buttons for 'full update' and 'send updates', where it tracks manual changes automatically and then when 'send updates' is hit, it backs up all the manual changes to a backup DB so that the next time you hit 'full update' it has those manual changes automatically

Now, I joined this company in their rotational program and started in an area that normally doesn't get computer engineers so they tasked me with improving this 'database viewer'. So initially I went through some options and this is what I did:

Major Improvements:

- I combed through the VBA and rewrote everything in Python using mainly Pandas and XLwings. Now the 'full update' takes anywhere from 2-5 minutes performing almost identical queries(I tried to improve the SQL as much as possible too)
- I don't print as much data to the spreadsheet since I can just manipulate it in a dataframe now so the sheet performs better

So again, my question would be, are there ways to generally improve this whole process? Whether its keeping it in excel and redoing the program in another language? Or would scrapping excel and moving to another application be better? I'm just looking for suggestions to look into because I'm not familiar with how this is typically done in "Industry".

Comment: Sorry but this site is for posting questions which existing software to use for a specific job. Questions on self-developed programs better suite to stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @Robert, ok, I wasn't sure. I thought that on stackoverflow this might be too opinion-based, thank you

Comment: But I would recommend to reformulate your question: it is a bit long. Just describe what you have at the moment including relevant code snippets and what the problem is.

Comment: As Robert pointed out: SR is about recommending software that meets specific requirements – not about [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [code fragments](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), etc. If you can rephrase your question accordingly, we can reopen it – but as it's now, it's off-topic. Unfortunately I don't know another SE site it might fit on either.